# When is a dataset called unbalanced?

Tags: machine-learning

I've a dataset (based on million song dataset) on which I need to do genre classification. Following is the distribution of various genre classes in the dataset.

```
Genre   Count   %age

 1. Rock    115104  39.94364359
 2. Pop     47534   16.49535337
 3. Electronic  24313   8.437150809
 4. Jazz    16465   5.713720564
 5. Rap     15347   5.325749741
 6. RnB 13769   4.778148706
 7. Country 13509   4.687922933
 8. Reggae  8739    3.032627027
 9. Blues   7075    2.455182083
 10. Latin  7042    2.44373035
 11. Metal  6257    2.171317921
 12. World  4624    1.604630664
 13. Folk   3661    1.270448283
 14. Punk   3479    1.207290242
 15. New Age    1248    0.433083709
```

Would you call this data unbalanced? I've tried reading around but found that people describe datasets unbalanced where one of the classes is 99% of the dataset and it's a binary classification problem. Not sure whether the above set falls into this category. Please help. I'm not able to get the classification right and being a newbie can't decide whether it's the data or my naivety. This is one of the hypotheses I have and need to validate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no strict definition of imbalanced dataset, but generally, if the smallest class is 10x smaller than the largest one, then calling it imbalanced is a good idea.

In your case, smallest class is actually 100x smaller than the biggest one, so you can even map it onto your consideration of "99-1" for binary classification. If you only ask about differentiating between New Age and Rock you will end up with 99-1 imbalance, so you can expect problems typical to imbalanced classification - to appear in your project.